# Is there a way to use currentColor in SASS color functions?

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning SASS and I tried to use `background-color: darken(currentColor, 25%);` to make the background color darker than the text, but when I tried to transpile it to CSS, I got an error message that `currentColor` is not a color.

I kind of understand why this happens, but I can't find a way to make it work, and I have a reason to keep using `currentColor`. Is there a way to make SASS perform color functions on `currentColor`?

Comment: not possible with Sass but somehow possible with CSS